# jquery hovering li to show inside paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

simple jquery code to show paragraph only when hovering the LI

```
<ol id="sortme">
<li>this content <p class="edit">first hidden content</p></li>
<li>this content <p class="edit">second hidden content</p></li>
<li>this content <p class="edit">third hidden content</p></li>
</ol>
```

Jquery

```
$(".edit").hide;
$('#sortme li').hover(
                function () {
                  $(".edit").show();
                },
                function () {
                  $(".edit").hide();
                 }
              );
```

my problem is when hovering any of li all paragraph's appear
i need to do it one by on one
so when hovering the first li "first hidden content" appear
and when hovering the second li "first hidden content" disappear and "second hidden content"

and so on for the rest of list

Comment: I think that <p> is better suited as a <span> the way you're using it.  Also, "#sortme > li > span" would save you the effort of having to classify them while allowing you to easily select em.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search in `this` context by supplying it as second parameter into `$()`:

```
$(".edit").hide;
$('#sortme li').hover(
    function () {
        $(".edit", this).show();
    },
    function () {
         $(".edit", this).hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: Exactly, instead of the thought like Marco had of "first hidden content" you should think of it as the edit class inside of the current element.

Answer (score 1):

Do this -

```
$('#sortme li').hover( function () {
     $(this).find(".edit").show();
   },
   function () {
     $(this).find(".edit").hide();
   });
```

OR

```
 $('#sortme li').hover(function () {
   $(this).find(".edit").toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply show hide to `children of current` li having class `edit` `instead` of applying to `every element` having class `edit`

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/ahepeq/1/edit)**

```
$(".edit").hide;
$('#sortme li').hover(
   function () {
         $(this).find('.edit').show();
    },
    function () {
         $(this).find('.edit').hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: It is the first with live demo, isn't it. I was busy for that. Shall I delete it?

Comment: That's ok - it just looks the same as above, nothing else :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same effect using CSS only.
http://jsfiddle.net/LNsaa/

```
#sortme p {
    display: none;
}

#sortme li:hover > p {
    display: block;
}​
```

You can then apply CSS3 transitions for some nice and smooth effects.